# IA32 Assembly Move Instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm trying to understand a `mov` instruction in assembly. It looks like this:

```
mov 0x804a12c(,%eax,4),%eax
```

I know that we are moving a new result into `%eax` and that `0x804a12c` is an address, but I don't get the `(,%eax,4)` part.

Any insight? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `0x804a12c(,%eax,4)` piece is a mode of addressing in x86. The parts of this can be broken out like this:

```
DISPLACEMENT(BASE,INDEX,WIDTH )
```

and the actually address is computed by the formula:

```
BASE + (INDEX * WIDTH ) + DISPLACEMENT
```

So the instruction:

```
mov 0x804a12c(,%eax,4),%eax
```

Moves `0 + (%eax * 4) + 0x804a12c` into the `%eax` register.

Answer (score 0):

This moves the dword at memory address `0x804a12c + %eax * 4` into `%eax`. You might expect an instruction like that to be an access at a computed index of a global array of, say, ints.

Answer (score 0):

This is why I *hate* AT&T syntax! In Intel syntax, it's much easier to see what's going on:

```
00000000  8B04852CA10408    mov eax, [eax*4 + 0x804a12c]
```

Note that the source/destination operands are switched in Intel syntax. Somewhat confusing at first, but this way it's just like C (imagine an `=` in place of the comma).

You can tell `objdump` to output Intel syntax with `objdump -d -M intel`.